# Syntax error in python 3.3.2

Tags: python, syntax

Trying to make a basic game as a first project on Python, when I try to run it it flashes the console and says "syntax error".

Thanks for any advice in advance. It's meant to start the attack sequence when you type attest in the first screen, so far the only attack is punch though.

Also, I know my code is dreadful and inefficient, but this is the first project I've made.

http://pastebin.com/bnneR6cf

Comment: Does it say a line number? Can we see the full error? That's too much code to just glance at and see what's going on.

Comment: Next time... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you know what a syntax error is?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error It means that what you wrote isn't actually valid Python.  Usually the error message includes a line number that is useful to within 1 line or block to find the error in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 26, you forgot a colon:

```
if monshp==0:
```

But really, you could've deduced this much yourself from the line number you get on exception.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see the line number because of the fun habit of closing the console a fraction of a second after it flashes the error code.